# Cannot convert value of type 'UILabel' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Tags: swift, string, label, constraints

I cant get my nameLbl to convert.

```
override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        addSubview(nameLbl)
        addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: nameLbl)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
views: nameLbl
```

you have to pass a Dictionary -- > `[String:Any]` as a parameter not a `UILabel` as the error states

```
views:[String:Any]
```

//

a correct syntax would be like this

```
let views: [String: UILabel] = ["nameLbl": nameLbl]
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[nameLbl(150)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
```

Answer (score 0):

Views need a dictionary not a view. You need to use a dictionary (in your case) like this:

```
let views: [String: Any] = ["v0": nameLbl]
```

them:

```
addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `constraints(withVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:)` takes a Dictionary of type `[String:Any]` for the `views` parameter. You've named your label `v0` in your constraint string, so you should use

```
let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
  withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", 
  options: [], 
  metrics: nil, 
  views: ["v0" : nameLbl])
addConstraints(constraints)
```

(note that the function `constraints(withVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:)` returns an array of constraints so you don't need to enclose it in braces. If you **do** enclose it in braces you'll have an array containing an array of constraints, which is not what you want.)